# Is the Wilcoxon paired rank test appropriate for this data?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two vectors of normalized data values representing two paired conditions ("methylation" and "expression"). A scatterplot of my data looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to know if I am using the Wilcoxon signed-rank test correctly in order to answer some questions. Specifically, I would like to identify those data points whose difference differs significantly from the median.

The p-value that `wilcox.test()` reports in R suggests that the alternative hypothesis is true (that the median of the difference of the two conditions is not zero, or that H<sub>0</sub> fails):

```
> wilcox.test(mtx$methylation_difference_normalized, mtx$expression_difference_normalized, alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE, exact = FALSE, correct = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)
V = 57049625, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2722975 0.3382661
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median
 0.3250247
```

Assuming this is the case, is the confidence interval that is reported usable for identifying points in the scatterplot which are significant?

Given this result, for example, can I simply take the (absolute?) difference of any pair of observations, and if that difference falls outside this interval, do I identify that data point as statistically significant?

Failing that, is there another test I should be using instead to accomplish the same task?

Comment: The p-value the `wilcox.test()` reports states the probability of finding data *as extreme or more extreme than yours, **IF** the null hypothesis is true*, nothing else. Specifically, it does not suggest "that the alternative hypothesis is true". I'm sorry for being a little pedantic, but it's important to be clear on exactly what statistical significance means.

Comment: `if that difference falls outside this interval, do I identify that data point as statistically significant?` Statistical tests usually are about all data points as a whole because they test hypotheses about populations. How do you imagine each separate point to refer to a population on its own?